# TSQL Where clause based on temp table data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a straight forward SQL query that I am working with and trying to figure out the best way to approach the `where` clause.

Essentially, there are two temp tables created and if there is data in the XML string passed to the stored procedure, those tables are populated.

My `where` clause needs to check these temp tables for data, and if there is no data, it ignores them like they are not there and fetches all data.

```
    -- Create temp tables to hold our XML filter criteria
    DECLARE @users AS TABLE (QID VARCHAR(10))
    DECLARE @dls   AS TABLE (dlName VARCHAR(50))

    -- Insert our XML filters
    IF @xml.exist('/root/data/users') > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @users( QID )
        SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('QID[1]', 'varchar(10)')
        FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data/users/user') AS ParamValues(x1)
    END
    IF @xml.exist('/root/data/dls') > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @dls( dlName )
        SELECT ParamValues.x1.value('dlName[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        FROM   @xml.nodes('/root/data/dld/dl') AS ParamValues(x1)
    END

    -- Fetch our document details based on the XML provided
    SELECT d.documentID ,
           d.sopID ,
           d.documentName ,
           d.folderLocation ,
           d.userGroup ,
           d.notes 
    FROM dbo.Documents AS d
    LEFT JOIN dbo.DocumentContacts AS dc
    ON dc.documentID = d.documentID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.DocumentContactsDLs AS dl
    ON dl.documentID = d.documentID
    -- How can I make these two logic checks work only if there is data, otherwise, include everything.
    WHERE dc.QID IN (SELECT QID FROM @users)
    AND dl.DL IN (SELECT dlName FROM @dls)

    FOR    XML PATH ('data'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root');
```

In the query above, I am trying to used the data in the temp tables only if there is data in them, otherwise, it needs to act like that `where` statement isn't there for that specific value and include records regardless.

Example: If only `@users` had data, it would ignore `AND dl.DL IN (SELECT dlName FROM @dls)` and get everything, regardless of what was in the `DL` column on those joined records.

Comment: Why can't you use a IF ELSE condition?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to check the existence of any record in `variable` table. Here is one way

```
WHERE  ( dc.QID IN (SELECT QID FROM @users)
          OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @users) )
       AND ( dl.DL IN (SELECT dlName FROM @dls)
              OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dls) )
```

Comment: If I have two primary records and one of them has a a record in the `@users` table and the other does not, is this going to meet both conditions and include both records (don't want that).

Comment: @SBB - sorry I didnt get that. Can you add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But please note that I did not get a chance to test it properly and I believe that you want to check the values in @users first and if there is no record existing in that table, then you want to check with the entries in @dls. Also if there are no entries in both of these tables, then you want to skip both the tables.

```
DECLARE @fl bit = 0
SELECT @fl = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @users) THEN 
 1
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @dls) THEN  
2
ELSE 
0
END

WHERE  (    (dc.QID IN (SELECT QID FROM @users) AND @fl = 1)
        OR 
            (dl.DL IN (SELECT dlName FROM @dls) AND @fl = 2)
        OR  (1=1 AND @fl = 0)
        )
```